# how to read messages in kafka using Spark Scala API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, hbase, spark-streaming

I am unable to receive messages in msgItr where as in command promt  using kafka commands i am able to see the messages in partition. please let me know what is going on here. what should i do get the messages.

I tried to print but nothing prints. May be because it is an RDD and it is printing something on the executor node.

```
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(props.getProperty("spark.streaming.batchDuration").toInt))

val topics = Set(props.getProperty("kafkaConf.topic"))

// TODO: Externalize StorageLevel to props file
val storageLevel: StorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2

//"zookeeper.connect" -> "fepp-cdhmn-d2.fepoc.com"
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  // the usual params, make sure to change the port in bootstrap.servers if 9092 is not TLS
  "zookeeper.connect" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.zookeeper.connect"),
  "bootstrap.servers" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.bootstrap.servers"),
  "group.id" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.group.id"),
  "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms"),
  "security.protocol" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.security.protocol"),
  "ssl.protocol" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.protocol"),
  "ssl.keymanager.algorithm" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.keymanager.algorithm"),
  "ssl.enabled.protocols" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.enabled.protocols"),
  "ssl.truststore.type" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.truststore.type"),
  "ssl.keystore.type" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.keystore.type"),
  "ssl.truststore.location" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.truststore.location"),
  "ssl.truststore.password" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.truststore.password"),
  "ssl.keystore.location" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.keystore.location"),
  "ssl.keystore.password" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.keystore.password"),
  "ssl.key.password" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.ssl.key.password"),
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "auto.offset.reset" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.auto.offset.reset"),
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (props.getProperty("kafkaConf.enable.auto.commit").toBoolean: java.lang.Boolean),
  "key.serializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
  "value.serializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
  //"heartbeat.interval.ms" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.heartbeat.interval.ms"),
  //"session.timeout.ms" -> props.getProperty("kafkaConf.session.timeout.ms")
)

// Must use the direct api as the old api does not support SSL
log.debug("Creating direct kafka stream")
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))


val res = kafkaStream.foreachRDD((kafkaRdd: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]) => {
          val numPartitions = kafkaRdd.getNumPartitions
          log.info(s"Processing RDD with '$numPartitions' partitions.")

      // Only one partition for the kafka topic is supported at this time
      if (numPartitions != 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Kafka topic must have 1 partition")
      }

      val offsetRanges = kafkaRdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

      kafkaRdd.foreachPartition((msgItr: Iterator[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]) => {

        val log = LogManager.getRootLogger()


        msgItr.foreach((kafkaMsg: ConsumerRecord[String, String]) => {

 // Hbase connection Fails here. because of authentication with below error


2018-09-19 15:28:01 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.home=/home/service_account
2018-09-19 15:28:01 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.dir=/data/09/yarn/nm/usercache/service_account/appcache/application_1536891989660_9297/container_e208_1536891989660_9297_01_000002
2018-09-19 15:28:01 INFO  ZooKeeper:438 - Initiating client connection, connectString=depp-cdhmn-d1.domnnremvd.com:2181,depp-cdhmn-d2.domnnremvd.com:2181,depp-cdhmn-d3.domnnremvd.com:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x16648f570x0, quorum=depp-cdhmn-d1.domnnremvd.com:2181,depp-cdhmn-d2.domnnremvd.com:2181,depp-cdhmn-d3.domnnremvd.com:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2018-09-19 15:28:01 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server depp-cdhmn-d3.domnnremvd.com/999.99.999.777:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2018-09-19 15:28:01 INFO  ClientCnxn:852 - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /999.99.999.999:33314, server: depp-cdhmn-d3.domnnremvd.com/999.99.999.777:2181
2018-09-19 15:28:01 INFO  ClientCnxn:1235 - Session establishment complete on server depp-cdhmn-d3.domnnremvd.com/999.99.999.777:2181, sessionid = 0x365cb965ff33958, negotiated timeout = 60000
false
false
2018-09-19 15:28:02 WARN  UserGroupInformation:1923 - PriviledgedActionException as:service_account (auth:SIMPLE) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
2018-09-19 15:28:02 WARN  RpcClientImpl:675 - Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
2018-09-19 15:28:02 ERROR RpcClientImpl:685 - SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:618)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$700(RpcClientImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:741)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:741)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:874)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:58383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTableNames(HBaseAdmin.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTableNames(HBaseAdmin.java:517)
    at com.company.etl.HbaseConnect.mainMethod(HbaseConnect.scala:39)
    at com.company.etl.App$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(App.scala:205)
    at com.company.etl.App$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(App.scala:178)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.foreach(KafkaRDD.scala:189)
    at com.company.etl.App$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(App.scala:178)
    at com.company.etl.App$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(App.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Have you looked at the executor logs? Where are you expecting it to print? Have you set a group id and not consumed from the beginning of the topic?

Comment: I have setup group id. if i use terminal and below command it works and prints messages                          /usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer \
--bootstrap-<Server> \
--topic "${TOPIC}" \
--consumer.config /opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-2.1.1-1.2.1.1.p0.18/etc/kafka/conf.dist/consumer.properties \
--new-consumer \
--from-beginning \
--timeout-ms 2000

Comment: it is not going in to the msgItr loop. i have explicit exception thrown even then it wont work.

Comment: Basically, RDD API is considered "stable", and no new features or fixes are going into it, so Structured Streaming (and DataFrames) are 
 the alternative. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: I found the issue, in cloudera Hbase is on Thrift server and kerberos authentications is happening through Hadoop. But when processing data in kafka some how namenode is executing  connection on data node and kerberos authentication is not happening.

Comment: Kafka doesn't depend on any of those services, though. Kerberos is optional

Comment: I added the error i am getting in the post

Comment: If you are trying to write from Kafka to HBase, generally it is easier to use Kafka Connect rather than write your own Spark code... Plus, Kafka Connect scales better than deploying Spark in YARN

Answer (score 2):

It's because of kerberos authentications.

Set System Properties.

```
  System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","/your/conf/directory/kafkajaas.conf");
  System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug","true");
  System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/your/krb5/conf/directory/krb5.conf");
```

You can read data from Cloudera Kafka. (Producer)

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xx.xx.xx.xx:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "test")
  .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_PLAINTEXT")
  .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka")
```

You can write data to Cloudera Kafka topic (Consumer)

```
val query = blacklistControl.select(to_json(struct("Column1","Column2")).alias("value"))
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/your/empty/directory")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xx.xx.xx.xx:9092")
  .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_PLAINTEXT")
  .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka")
  .option("topic", "topic_xdr")
  .start()
```

Comment: i have added the properties i am using. not sure about the jaas security property you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

i faced exactly the same  issue. What is happening is  the executor node is trying to write to hbase and doesnt have the credentials . What you need to do is pass the keytab file to the executors and explicitly call the KDC authentication WITH In THe executor block

UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hdfs-user@MYCORP.NET", 
   "/home/hdfs-user/hdfs-user.keytab");

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace, it looks like the kafka is authenticated with `sasl`. 
The supported SASL mechanims are:

1. GSSAPI (Kerberos)
2. OAUTHBEARER
3. SCRAM
4. PLAIN

> From your stacktrace, kafka is configured using `GSSAPI` and you need to
>   authenticate accordingly. You are authenticating for `SSL` and not
>   `SASL`.  Check the [this link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_gssapi.html) for steps to authenticate.